# How to automate answers to the new create-next-app?

Tags: next.js

The next `npx create-next-app@latest` asks a bunch of questions. They break our automatic docker pipeline.

How can we automate them?

Right now, we use this command in our `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN npx --yes create-next-app site --use-npm
```

However, it asks two questions:

> Would you like to use TypeScript with this project? … No / Yes
> Would you like to use ESLint with this project? › No / Yes

How can we provide answer to these questions alonside the `npx` command?

Answer (score 2):

Taking a look at the [source code](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/create-next-app/index.ts), if you specify either `--js` or `--ts`, you won't be prompted. Similarly, you can specify `--eslint` *or* `--no-eslint`.